# Is there an easy way to minimize the common ES6 function I've written to filter empty key values, array structure, check special character in 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write a common function that removes empty keys and values, removes if one attribute not present and also remove the objects if value attribute it doesn't match the searched items.

Here is the code:

```js
    let array1 = [
        {
          "Product": "Tv",
          "Amount": "$5000"
        },
        {
          "Product": "Refrigerator",
          "Amount": "$0"
        },
        {
          "Product": null,
          "Amount": "$500"
        },
        {
          "Amount": "$5000"
        },
        {
          "Product": "A/c",
          "Amount": null
        },
        {
          "Product": "Heater",
        }
      
      ];
      
    let array2 = [
        {
          "Type": "Grocery",
          "Value": "$9000"
        },
        {
          "Type": "Insurance",
          "Value": "7%"
        },
        {
          "Type": "Home Loan",
          "Value": "0%"
        },
        {
          "Value": "$5000"
        },
        {
          "Type": null,
          "Value": "$1000"
        },
        {
          "Type": "Shopping",
        }
      
      ];

    const filterEmptyKeysAndValues = (arrayObj) => {
        let filterItems = ["$0", "0%", "0"];
        const finalObj= arrayObj.filter(({ Product }) => Product)
          .filter(({ Amount }) => Amount)
          .filter(({ type }) => type)
          .filter(({ value }) => value)
          .filter(obj => obj && !filterItems.includes(obj.Amount))
          .filter(obj => obj && !filterItems.includes(obj.value));
        return finalObj;
      }
    let FinalArray1;
    let FinalArray2;
    FinalArray1 = filterEmptyKeysAndValues(array1);
    FinalArray2 = filterEmptyKeysAndValues(array2);
```

Is there a way that can reduce the code and check these conditions? Instead of naming each key name, can we write a common code that checks for all the keys and values in 2 arrays.

Comment: Please fix the formatting

Comment: That's a topic for https://codereview.stackexchange.com - but first read their help section/rules.

Comment: @Andreas - what do you mean by formatting? It's already formatted right?

Comment: Stuarts edit made it better. But there's still text in the code block that doesn't belong there (at least not in its current form)

Comment: can you please mention what are they

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: I've edited the code. Does anyone have any better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could create a custom filter based on Object.entries, ensuring that objects have:

1. More than 1 property
2. None of these are in the array ["$0", "0%", "0"]
3. Properties must be *truthy*

One could pass the array of illegal items, by default ["$0", "0%", "0"]

```js
let array1 = [ { "Product": "Tv", "Amount": "$5000" }, { "Product": "Refrigerator", "Amount": "$0" }, { "Product": null, "Amount": "$500" }, { "Amount": "$5000" }, { "Product": "A/c", "Amount": null }, { "Product": "Heater", }  ];
let array2 = [ { "Type": "Grocery", "Value": "$9000" }, { "Type": "Insurance", "Value": "7%" }, { "Type": "Home Loan", "Value": "0%" }, { "Value": "$5000" }, { "Type": null, "Value": "$1000" }, { "Type": "Shopping", }  ];
   
 
function objectFilter(obj) {
    return Object.entries(obj).filter(([k,v]) => k && v && !["$0", "0%", "0"].includes(v)).length > 1;
}
 
console.log("Array 1, filtered:", array1.filter(objectFilter))
console.log("Array 2, filtered:", array2.filter(objectFilter))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have to tell JS interpreter which keys you expect to be present in the object. Otherwise, it can check only the keys which already exist.
Example:

```
{
  "Amount": "$5000"
}
```

We can't know whether this Object should have some other key-value pair unless you specify it somehow

Try to see whether this works for you

```
let filterFunc = (arr) => {
    let filterItems = ["$0", "0%", "0"]; //custom incorrect values
    let keysInObjects = Array.from(new Set(arr.flatMap((item) => Object.keys(item))))
    return arr.filter((item) => keysInObjects.every((key) => Object.keys(item).includes(key)) && Object.values(item).every((value) => !!value && !filterItems.includes(value)))
}
```

First, we aggregate all keys from all objects into an array, and then we check whether all objects contain all keys and if all the values are correct

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable to check any of the fields for the filter items, you can do this:

```
const filterEmptyKeysAndValues = arr => {
    const filterItems = [null, undefined, "$0", "0%", "0"];
    const keys = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...arr))
    return arr.filter(record => keys.every(key => !filterItems.includes(record[key]));
}
```

or if you need to limit the search for filter items to fields such as `Amount` or `Value`:

```
const filterEmptyKeysAndValues = (arr, filterFields) => {
    const filterItems = [undefined, "$0", "0%", "0"];
    const keys = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...arr))
    return arr.filter(record => 
        keys.every(key => record[key] !== undefined && record[key] !== null)
        && filterFields.every(key => !filterItems.includes(record[key]))
    );
}
```

which you would then call like this

```
filterEmptyKeysAndValues(array1, ["Amount"])
```